# How does one suppress specific warnings from source code on g++ 4.5 or later?

Tags: c++, g++, compiler-warnings, warnings

The first comment on [a feature request for g++](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=45203) says, "Starting with 4.5 you can disable a class of warnings in the source."

I looked through the 4.5.0 manual, but I can't find the syntax.

What is the syntax in g++ 4.5 and later to suppress individual warning classes in the source?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Pragmas.html

http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Diagnostic-Pragmas.html#Diagnostic-Pragmas